# Python DRY class inititialization

Tags: python-3.x

What is the pythonic way to initialize a class, without repeating oneself too much? What I see done frequently, but what feels wasteful is the following:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None, c=None,...)
        if a is None:
            a = a_default_value()
        if b is None:
            b = b_default_value()
        if c is None:
            c = c_default_value()

        assert sanity_check(a,b,c)

        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

It feels like a way to simplify the code a lot should be to loop over a dictionary (especially if there are many inputs):

```
class foo:
    defaults = {
        'a' : a_default_value(),
        'b' : b_default_value(),
        'c' : c_default_value()}

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key in set(self.defaults) - set(kwargs):
            kwargs[key] = self.defaults[key]

        assert self.sanity_check(**kwargs)

        for key in kwargs:
            setattr(self, key, kwargs[key])
```

But also that looks kind of ugly?! There must be a better way!

Comment: May this work? https://gist.github.com/fcracker79/c99359a0cf4b668ab2787c6b8273c9fb
In this implementation, all you have to do is define your defaults.
You may have noticed that I have removed the `sanity_check` invocation. It would take the whole kw arguments but, since there is no such implementation, these is no free food on how to implement it in a smart way.

Comment: Alternatively, you might create a complex object (you can create it following a builder pattern, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), then validate the whole object.
You might have a look at my project: https://github.com/fcracker79/pycomb

Comment: Sounds like you are re-implementing a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dataclasses.html) here? For python 3.6 and older, use [`attrs`](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/) for the same functionality.

Comment: Note that your second version (with the `defaults` dict) will not work as expected - it will yield the same results as the infamous "mutable default argument" gotcha (https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) , which is actually the reason why one uses `None` as default and an explicit test in the initializer instead of using default arguments whenever the default is mutable. And really, while it's indeed a bit boring, this is the kind of code you only have to write once, so better to keep it as explicit as possible for readability / maintainability.